# Can I install hadoop2 and its services in one pc with ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, installation

I want to install hadoop and study it, but now I only have one pc with ubuntu 13.10 installed.

But I learned that hadoop needs at least 3 nodes.

Is there any good way to install hadoop and its service in one node?

I need the hive,hdfs,hbase,MR service, I think.

Any help will be appreciated，thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop does not need 3 nodes, it can be installed in one node, though for making hadoop cluster you need more machines .

Apache Hadoop Pseudo-distributed mode installation helps you simulate a multi-node installation on a single node. Instead of installing hadoop on different servers, you can simulate it on a single server.

In a pseudo-distributed mode where each Hadoop daemon runs in a separate Java process.

Everything hive,hbase can be configured in psedu-distributed mode.

Please follow [this useful tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).

Comment: OK,it talked about hadoop v1, but I think, it's also suit for v2 :-)

Comment: Yes it also suit for Hadoop 2.x or yarn .